# @jit slowing down function

Tags: python, jit, numba

I'm developing an optimization code for a complex reservoir operations problem. Part of this requires me to calculate the objective function for a large number of potential solutions. I'm testing the optimizer on the Rosenbrock function and trying to improve its speed. I noticed when I profiled the code that calculating the objective function within a for loop was one of the code bottlenecks so I developed a way to do this in parallel for multiple sets of decision variables.  I have two objective function calculators: FO for one set of decision variables and P_FO for multiple sets of decision variables. Calculation of the objective function is one of the slowest parts of my code so I would like to speed things up further using @jit. I tested both functions using @jit and am finding the P_FO function is slower with @jit than without it. The code is below:

```
import time
import numpy as np
from numba import jit 

def FO(X):
    #Rosenbrock function
    ObjV=0
    for i in range(65-1):
        F=100*((X[i+1]-X[i]**2)+(X[i]-1)**2)
        ObjV+=F
    return ObjV

t0=time.time()
X=10+np.zeros(65)
for i in range(5000):
    FO(X)
t1 = time.time()
total = t1-t0
print("time FO="+str(total))

@jit
def FO(X):
    #Rosenbrock function
    ObjV=0
    for i in range(65-1):
        F=100*((X[i+1]-X[i]**2)+(X[i]-1)**2)
        ObjV+=F
    return ObjV

t0=time.time()
X=10+np.zeros(65)
for i in range(5000):
    FO(X)
t1 = time.time()
total = t1-t0
print("time FO with @jit="+str(total))



def P_FO(X):
    ObjV=np.zeros(X.shape[0])  
    for i in range(X.shape[1]-1):
        F=100*((X[:,i+1]-X[:,i]**2)+(X[:,i]-1)**2)
        ObjV+=F
    return ObjV       

t0=time.time()
X=10+np.zeros((65, 5000))
P_FO(X)
t1 = time.time()
total = t1-t0
print("time P_FO="+str(total))


@jit
def P_FO(X):
    ObjV=np.zeros(X.shape[0])  
    for i in range(X.shape[1]-1):
        F=100*((X[:,i+1]-X[:,i]**2)+(X[:,i]-1)**2)
        ObjV+=F
    return ObjV       

t0=time.time()
X=10+np.zeros((65, 5000))
P_FO(X)
t1 = time.time()
total = t1-t0
print("time P_FO with @jit="+str(total))
```

Results were:

```
time FO=0.523999929428
time FO with @jit=0.0720000267029
time P_FO=0.0380001068115
time P_FO with @jit=0.229000091553
```

Can anyone point me to a reason why @jit slows down the parallel objective function P_FO? Is it because of the use of np.zeros or perhaps array.shape()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

numba functions are compiled lazily, i.e., not until called the first time, so your timings are a capturing the one-time compilation overhead.  If I call each function once before running the timing sections, I get:

```
time FO=0.4103426933288574
time FO with @jit=0.0020008087158203125
time P_FO=0.04154801368713379
time P_FO with @jit=0.004002809524536133
```

Comment: That makes sense. Since I'll be running it up to 300 times per simulation (and millions of simulations), it may still improve results.

Comment: Just curious - if the @jit function is in another .py file, does it have to compile every time its called? Or will compiling it once from my main function speed it up for the rest of the function calls?

Comment: No, once imported, the compilation needs to be done only once.  Even better, there is a `cache=True` option that can cache the compilation across python sessions. See docs at http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit.html#cache